# CasperJS Javascript not loading

Tags: javascript, xpath, phantomjs, casperjs

```js
var casper = require('casper').create({
  verbose: true,
  logLevel: 'error',
  pageSettings: {
    loadImages: false,
    loadPlugins: false,
    javascriptEnabled: true,
    userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.2 Safari/537.36'
  }
});
var x = require("casper").selectXPath;

casper.start("https://kit.kijiji.ca/Index.aspx");

// http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message
casper.on("remote.message", function(msg) {
  this.echo("Console: " + msg);
});

// http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error
casper.on("page.error", function(msg, trace) {
  this.echo("Error: " + msg);
  // maybe make it a little fancier with the code from the PhantomJS equivalent
});

// http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#resource-error
casper.on("resource.error", function(resourceError) {
  this.echo("ResourceError: " + JSON.stringify(resourceError, undefined, 4));
});

// http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-initialized
casper.on("page.initialized", function(page) {
  // CasperJS doesn't provide `onResourceTimeout`, so it must be set through 
  // the PhantomJS means. This is only possible when the page is initialized
  page.onResourceTimeout = function(request) {
    console.log('Response Timeout (#' + request.id + '): ' + JSON.stringify(request));
  };
});

casper.then(function() {
  this.sendKeys('input[name="login_username"]', 'example@example.com');
  this.sendKeys('input[name="login_password"]', 'password');
});

casper.thenClick('button', function() {
  this.echo("Button clicked.");
});

casper.wait(500, function() {
  casper.click(x("//input[@value='Login / Ouvrir une session']"));
});

casper.wait(1500, function() {
  this.echo(this.getTitle());

  this.download(this.getCurrentUrl(), 'logged_in_info.html');

  this.capture('example.png');
  casper.exit();
});

casper.run();
```

I'm currently running PhantomJS 2.1.1 and the latest version of CasperJS. All day I've been trying to get this to work but to no hope.

I'm opening up the webpage, filling in the credentials and then logging in. It all works well but the problem I'm having is that when I download the source it is completely different then from the source I would get just logging in from my browser.

I believe that some kind of Javascript file isn't being executed within CasperJS causing missing data.

For example, when I log in with my browser I'm able to see a table of data that is not there when I log in with CasperJS.

Any help would be spectacular. Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using `casper.download()`? You should use `fs.write(casper.getHTML(), 'content.html');` instead. `casper.download()` may not use a session, because it might forget to sent the session cookie.